# How do I eliminate rows that are within 24 hours of the previous row per id?

Tags: sql-server

YourTableName

| id | ep | timein | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EP-001 | 2023-07-20 12:00:00 | Team A |
| 1 | EP-001 | 2023-07-20 15:00:00 | Team A |
| 1 | EP-001 | 2023-07-22 15:30:00 | Team A |
| 1 | EP-001 | 2023-07-25 09:45:00 | Team A |
| 1 | EP-001 | 2023-07-28 11:20:00 | Team A |
| 1 | EP-001 | 2023-08-01 08:00:00 | Team A |
| 1 | EP-001 | 2023-08-01 12:00:00 | Team A |

The output below is what I am seeking

YourTableName

| id | ep | timein | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EP-001 | 2023-07-20 12:00:00 | Team A |
| 1 | EP-001 | 2023-07-22 15:30:00 | Team A |
| 1 | EP-001 | 2023-07-25 09:45:00 | Team A |
| 1 | EP-001 | 2023-07-28 11:20:00 | Team A |
| 1 | EP-001 | 2023-08-01 08:00:00 | Team A |

Comment: So if you have 10 rows for `id = 1` and they are all spaced out at 23 hour intervals covering the range from `2023-07-21 00:00:00` to `2023-07-29 15:00:00` you would only want the row for `2023-07-21 00:00:00`? Or are you really looking for something different? Such as max one row per day?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I just want to eliminate anything that is within 24 hours of the of any row above or below  it.

Comment: That hasn't clarified things. What is the desired results here? https://dbfiddle.uk/7ABue-ej - you don't want any row after `2023-08-01 08:00:00.000`?

Comment: The table at the bottom shows  that row 2 and 7 were removed because their timein was within 24 hours of the row above them. I'd like to rid of such rows.

Comment: What if your starting table had a row with the `timein` = `2023-07-19 13:00:00`. That would make it within 24 hours of `2023-07-20 12:00:00` and visa versa. Which row should be removed?

Comment: You keep not answering the question. My question three comments up was about the sample data that **I** constructed - so an answer that ignores that data and only references the data that you constructed is not an answer to that

Comment: Martin, my apologies. I missed that one. If there's any row after 2023-08-01 08:00:00.000 then it should be more than 24 hours, so in this case no.

Comment: @J.D. The second row please. The first row is always gonna get a pass. The row that follows the first must not be within 24 hours.

Comment: Ok so if you get rid of the second row in the example I gave, you'll end up keeping this row `2023-07-20 15:00:00` then, since it's no longer within 24 hours of any row before it. Right?

Comment: Yes. Exactly @J.D.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Martin's answer should accomplish what you need. Time range questions like these can be a little confusing to define (hence all these clarification comments).

Comment: @ J.D. What about this> https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/329571/how-do-i-query-for-actives-users-at-a-certain-point-in-time-by-year-month

Comment: @SamJohnson Heads up, I didn't see your last comment reply because I think there's an extra space between the @ symbol and my name. I'll take a look at one when I get a chance.

Comment: @J.D. Thank you

Comment: @J.D. Any chance with this: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/329571/how-do-i-query-for-actives-users-at-a-certain-point-in-time-by-year-month

Answer (score 1):

For the question as stated this seems fairly straight forward.

You can use [`LAG`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) to see what the previous row's timein was and then validate that the current row's timein is at least that plus 24 hours.

([Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/B7pPR1mK))

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                PreviousTimeIn = LAG(timein)
                                   OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY timein)
         FROM   YourTableName)
SELECT id,
       ep,
       timein,
       team
FROM   T
WHERE  PreviousTimeIn IS NULL
        OR timein >= DATEADD(HOUR, 24, PreviousTimeIn)
```

I am assuming that `timein` is not nullable so we can just use `PreviousTimeIn IS NULL` to detect the first row in a partition (where there is no previous row to validate against).

Comment: Thank you @Martin Smith!

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from t
where not exists (select * from t as t1 where t1.id=t.id
     and Dateadd(hour,-24,t.timein)<t1.timein and t1.timein<t.timein)
order by id, timein
```

However in your example there will be only one record with 2023-07-21 08:30:00 for id=1 and one record with time 2023-07-22 08:30:00 for id=2 so it's probably not good data to express your problem.

Comment: I made changes to the table. sorry about that