# how do I capture the active years & months between start date & end date for ids under Team A?

Tags: sql-server

| id | status | startdate | enddate | team |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | closed | 2015-02-01 | 2015-03-01 | A |
| 2 | active | 2015-01-05 | NULL | A |
| 4 | closed | 2022-07-01 | 2023-06-05 | D |

I'd like to replicate what's below from the the table above for closed ids only:

| id | year | month |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2015 | 2 |
| 1 | 2015 | 3 |
| 4 | 2022 | 7 |
| 4 | 2022 | 8 |
| 4 | 2022 | 9 |
| 4 | 2022 | 10 |
| 4 | 2022 | 11 |
| 4 | 2022 | 12 |
| 4 | 2023 | 1 |
| 4 | 2023 | 2 |
| 4 | 2023 | 3 |
| 4 | 2023 | 4 |
| 4 | 2023 | 5 |
| 4 | 2023 | 6 |

I managed something but is there a way to make it run quicker cause my actual table has over 29k ids with closed status? it's take a long time to run.

Comment: Why downvote  without providing a reason? If something does not make sense then make it known. I've had this up for a few days but no response so I tweaked it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are close, but you could speed it up dramatically by having the recursive portion more limited rather than doing it for each entity + date range.

Take a look at the below.  Possible speed up by putting the results of the recursive section into a temp table or otherwise storing the results, but I think this should be fairly quick as is.  If you are on SQL 2022+ or have access to GENERATE_SERIES then you can build up a date table fairly easily.

You may want to change how the @EndDate variable is populated, it could be set to the current day, or some other future state, but for now it's set to the maximum end date for a "closed" entity.

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE 
    (
    ID INT NULL
    , [Status] NVARCHAR(20) NULL
    , StartDate DATE NULL
    , EndDate DATE NULL
    , Team NCHAR(1) NULL
    )

INSERT INTO @TestTable 
    (ID, [Status], StartDate, EndDate, Team)
VALUES (1, 'closed', '2/1/2015', '3/1/2015', 'A')
    , (2, 'active', '1/5/2015', NULL, 'A')
    , (4, 'closed', '7/1/2022', '6/5/2023', 'D')

SELECT * FROM @TestTable

DECLARE @StartDate DATE
DECLARE @EndDate DATE 

SELECT @StartDate = MIN(StartDate) 
    , @EndDate = MAX(EndDate)
FROM @TestTable AS T
WHERE T.[Status] = 'closed'

;WITH CTE_Recursion AS
    (
    SELECT YEAR(@StartDate) AS [YEAR]
        , MONTH(@StartDate) AS [MONTH]
        , @StartDate AS StartDate
    UNION ALL
    SELECT YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, R.StartDate)) AS [YEAR]
        , MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, R.StartDate)) AS [MONTH]
        , DATEADD(MONTH, 1, R.StartDate) AS StartDate
    FROM CTE_Recursion AS R
    WHERE DATEADD(MONTH, 1, R.StartDate) <= @EndDate
    )
SELECT T.*
    , R.YEAR 
    , R.MONTH 
FROM @TestTable AS T
    LEFT OUTER JOIN CTE_Recursion AS R ON R.StartDate BETWEEN T.StartDate AND T.EndDate
WHERE T.[Status] = 'closed'
ORDER BY T.ID, R.YEAR, R.MONTH 
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Comment: I will give this a shot. Thanks! Should I expect a faster response with 29k 'closed' ids if I follow this route?    I will give this a shot. Thanks! Should I expect a faster response with 29k 'closed' ids if I follow this route?

Comment: It should be faster, especially if you pop the results of CTE_Recursion into a temp table and then use it in the left outer join.

Answer (score -1):

```
WITH RecursiveMonths AS (
SELECT
    id,
    startdate AS project_date,
    YEAR(startdate) AS year,
    MONTH(startdate) AS month
FROM
    tst
WHERE
    status = 'closed'
    AND enddate IS NOT NULL

UNION ALL

SELECT
    p.id,
    DATEADD(MONTH, 1, rm.project_date),
    YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, rm.project_date)),
    MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, 1, rm.project_date))
FROM
    RecursiveMonths rm
INNER JOIN
    tst p ON rm.id = p.id
WHERE
    DATEADD(MONTH, 1, rm.project_date) <= p.enddate
)
SELECT
id,
year,
month
FROM
RecursiveMonths
ORDER BY
id, year, month;
```

Comment: You can answer your own question, but should not answer with the next question to the same problem.....  (They did invent an [edit](https://dba.stackexchange.com/posts/329571/edit) button to make life easy for you)

Comment: There is some explanation missing on what this is supposed to be, a comment? or an answer?

Comment: This is the answer I was able to produce.  Although this query works for  the sample table, my actual table has 29k closed ids. how do I get that to run and show results cause it's still running with no end in sight it seems.

Comment: Please do add this answer, which is not an answer to your question.

Comment: As mentioned, add the cooment to your answer and explsin the query. Then you have my vote